# Why "ever" used here in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Here is a quote from another Stack Exchange question:

> How was a vessel **ever** constructed that actually flew through Earth's
>   atmosphere without burning up, and then was able to travel around once
>   it reached space without just freezing up?
>
> [Source](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22590/how-did-people-know-how-to-build-the-first-space-ship)

What is the purpose of **ever** here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an intensifier. From NOAD:

> **intensifier** (*noun*) `Grammar` an adverb used to give force or emphasis, for example, *really* in *my feet are really cold*.

which goes along with this definition of *ever*, found in the same dictionary:

> **ever** (*adverb*) used for emphasis in questions and other remarks, expressing astonishment or outrage: *don't you ever forget it!*

In this case, I think the intensifier is intended to convey a feeling of skepticism or disbelief.

Answer (score 0):

It works as intensifier as J.R. says in his answer.

**ever** brings in the idea of  'all of time' and thus indirectly 'all possible circumstances' and so, in this skeptical question, it expresses the idea that the speaker believes something could *never* have been possible.

How was it possible under *any* set of circumstances....?

Compare *How could you ever think that I could betray you?*

Why would you think that I could betray you under *any* circumstances?